# Why rasqal configuration can't recognize the already raptor library on cygwin?

Tags: configuration, cygwin, redland, raptor2

I am trying to install rasqal 0.9.20 library http://librdf.org/rasqal/ onto a windows 7 machine with cygwin.Earlier i have successfully installed the raptor-2.2.0 library http://librdf.org/raptor/ and i can verify this with the rapper tool was created after the installation(./configure , ./make ,/make install)

The error that i am getting from the configuration of rasqal is :

```
    ./configure --enable-raptor2  
...  
    checking for raptor... configure: error: Raptor2 is not installed - see http://librdf.org/raptor/ to get a version newer than 1.9.0
```

I can't find a way to fix it. The code from the cofigure file that handles this flag is the below :

```
11840 # raptor is REQUIRED despite the checking here
11841 RAPTOR_MIN_VERSION=1.4.19
11842 RAPTOR_MAX_VERSION=1.8.99
11843 RAPTOR2_MIN_VERSION=1.9.0
11844
11845 raptor2=no
11846 # Check whether --enable-raptor2 was given.
11847 if test "${enable_raptor2+set}" = set; then :
11848   enableval=$enable_raptor2; raptor2="$enableval"
11849 else
11850   raptor2="no"
11851 fi
```

Comment: I found the bug.I copied the raptor.pc file under /usr/lib/pkgconfig and it worked

Comment: That's not a good idea.  Use configure --prefix=/usr to install things in the right place.  Read the INSTALL.html documents for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Raptor 2.0.0 uses only `pkg-config` to provide configuration information, `raptor-config` was removed.  The same applies to rasqal itself, the `rasqal-config` program will go away at some point.  The `--enable-raptor2` option to rasqal and librdf was for testing the beta raptor2, and it has been removed from rasqal 0.9.22 and librdf GIT head.

Comment: I tried to install the latest versions of redland library :                 raptor2-2.0.0                                                  rasqal-0.9.24
redland-1.0.13
redland-bindings-1.0.13.1 .I've succefully installed raptor, rasqal and redland after some changes as during redland lib configuration , raptor.pc and rasqal.pc were read from /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig and not from /usr/lib/pkgconfig, which was the correct dir.I tried to install the bindings and got a bunch of undefined references to python objects from Redland_wrap.so.e.g:"undefined reference to `__imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'"

Comment: You are asking a new question in a comment unrelated to the original question (pkg-config in cygwin) which is a bad use of StackOverflow.  If it is of general interest, make a new question.  Otherwise, take to email or one of the other documented redland feedback methods.

Comment: You are right.I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002194/why-cygwin-cannot-find-python-libraries-while-installing-python-redland-binding-l

Answer (score 0):

Set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to include the correct path:

```
env PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./configure
```

Another method, if available on your system, is to define the environment variable in /etc/environment:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```